# How to change background colour of a website when a button is clicked in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out when a user clicks an ASP.NET server button it changes the background color. Is there a way to do that without javascript in the code-behind file using c# without a body tag and just the  tag? And my next question is how would I save it in a cookie so when the user revisits the site their color scheme is kept.

Comment: Add a code snippet to show your work. No-one will write the code from scratch for you.

Comment: See also: [I downvoted because no MCVE provided](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). Try provide example code by editing question body instead of using comment.

Comment: I'm going to repost this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

in C#

```js
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyBody.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "red";    
}
```

in HTML

```html
<html>
<head><title>Change Background color</title></head>
<body id="MyBody"runat="server">
<h3>The background color of this page has been set programmatically.</h3>
<asp:Button id="Button1"Text="Click here for greeting..." OnClick="button1_Click"runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello @Serin Loly I am going to do this time but please show us your effort from next time. Keep coding

> default.aspx

```
<body id="bdy" runat="server">
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Button OnClick="eventclick" runat="server" Text="click" /> 
</form>
</body>
```

> cs code

```
 protected void eventclick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bdy.Attributes.Add("style", "background:teal");
    }
```